# Jenkins 2 NPM_TOKEN credential

Tags: jenkins, npm, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-2

I'm trying to run Jenkins 2 pipeline (Jenkinsfile) that will use `npm publish` to publish a package to local NPM repository.
In order to do that I've try to use the following stage in Jenkinsfile:

```
stage('TEST npm whoami') {
    withEnv(["PATH+NPM=${tool name: 'node-6', type: 'jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation'}/bin"]) {
    withCredentials([[$class: 'StringBinding', credentialsId: 'npm-token', variable: 'NPM_TOKEN']]) {
        sh """
           npm whoami
           """
    }
    }
}
```

Currently I'm running only `npm  whoami` and once that will work I'll replace it with `npm publish`.

This is the output I'm getting:

```
+ npm whoami
npm ERR! Linux 4.7.5-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64
npm ERR! argv "/var/lib/jenkins/tools/jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation/node-6/bin/node" "/var/lib/jenkins/tools/jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation/node-6/bin/npm" "whoami"
npm ERR! node v6.5.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.3
npm ERR! code ENEEDAUTH

npm ERR! need auth this command requires you to be logged in.
npm ERR! need auth You need to authorize this machine using `npm adduser`
```

Comment: Just to verify, credentialsId is usually a guid. Did you put 'npm-token' here for the idea? And what happens if you just `echo $NPM_TOKEN`

Answer (score 7):

From looking at [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/8356), it seems like `NPM_TOKEN` isn't something that npm itself recognizes, but rather a custom environment variable that heroku (and maybe other platforms) interpret.

What I've done, based on some of the discussion in that issue, is to create a project-level `.npmrc` at job execution time based on the token env var from my credential, then remove the file again before continuing. E.g.:

```
stage('TEST npm whoami') {
    withCredentials([string(
                credentialsId: 'npm-token',
                variable: 'NPM_TOKEN')]) {
        sh "echo //npm.skunkhenry.com/:_authToken=${env.NPM_TOKEN} > .npmrc"
        sh 'npm whoami'
        sh 'rm .npmrc'
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Slightly tweaked variant - with `.npmrc` written to the build server's `$HOME` dir and wrapped on a `try-catch` block that ensures the file's deleted every run:
~~~
    withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'NPM_TOKEN', variable: 'NPM_TOKEN')]) {
        String text = "//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=${env.NPM_TOKEN}"
        String npmrc = '\$HOME/.npmrc'
        writeFile file: npmrc, text: text
        try {
            sh 'npm publish'
        } finally {
            sh "rm ${npmrc}"
        }
    }
~~~

Answer (score 3):

The answer of Gerard Ryan and Gaston is correct, I just wanted to add one detail that I did not get at first:

If you want to use a private repository, the `.npmrc` should also specify the registry:

```
withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'registry', variable: 'token')]) {
            try {
                sh "echo registry=<your-registry-URL> >> .npmrc"
                sh "echo //<your-registry-URL>/:_authToken=${env.token} >> .npmrc"
                sh 'npm whoami'
            } finally {
                sh 'rm ~/.npmrc'
            }
}
```

Comment: Apparently, not all version of Jenkins will accept the `try { ... } finally { ... }` in this form. `Expected a step @ line 194, column 17.` `try {`

Comment: The `try...finally` block will only work with [Scripted Pipeline](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#scripted-pipeline).


With [Declarative Pipeline](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#declarative-pipeline) you will get something like the following error:
`WorkflowScript: 115: Expected a step @ line 115, column 13`

To fix that you should wrap it in `script` e.g. `script { try {withCredentials(){...}} finally {}}`

Comment: Please mind that in the response above `.npmrc` is created in a current directory while remove command attempts to remove it from user's `home` folder

Answer (score 1):

We can use [pipeline npm plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/pipeline-npm/)

and config pipeline

```
withNPM(npmrcConfig: 'my-custom-nprc') {
    sh 'npm install'
}
```